# How can I get the browser's scrollbar sizes?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

How can I determine the height of a horizontal scrollbar, or the width of a vertical one, in JavaScript?

Comment: Here is a snippet from the author of the JQuery Dimension plugin. http://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-getscrollbarwidth/blob/master/jquery.getscrollbarwidth.js maybe late to give this solution, but it seems a better one to me, IMO.

Comment: Have a look at this solution: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-scrollbar-width

Comment: @GibboK -- that solution fails -- the offsetWidth == clientWidth so it's always zero. This is tested in edge IE && Chrome.

Comment: @beauXjames weird it works for me on FF

Comment: This question arises in the situation in which the scrollbar is in the wrong location (somewhere in the middle of the screen). In this situation you probably do not want to show a scrollbar. In most cases I have found iScroll to be the perfect design-neutral solution for the situation: http://iscrolljs.com

Answer (score 153, accepted):

From [Alexandre Gomes Blog](http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=115)  I have not tried it.  Let me know if it works for you.

```
function getScrollBarWidth () {
  var inner = document.createElement('p');
  inner.style.width = "100%";
  inner.style.height = "200px";

  var outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.style.position = "absolute";
  outer.style.top = "0px";
  outer.style.left = "0px";
  outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  outer.style.width = "200px";
  outer.style.height = "150px";
  outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
  outer.appendChild (inner);

  document.body.appendChild (outer);
  var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
  var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
  if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

  document.body.removeChild (outer);

  return (w1 - w2);
};
```

Comment: The idea is genius, I'm definitely making a MooTools class based on this.

Comment: Yeah I got the same google result. :) I'm trying and keep you informed.

Comment: if you change your theme to one with different sized scroll bars what is the deviance in calculated to actual?

Comment: Changed the theme to Extra Large in windows, double checked in Normal size, the computation seems correct. I apparently counted wrongly.

Comment: see here for cross reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417139/how-do-i-calculate-the-height-of-toolbars-address-bars-and-other-navigation-tool/3417992#3417992

Comment: windows xp with ff7.0.1 requires `scr.style.overflow = 'auto';` you can add this under yet another another `if (w1 == w2)` in the above code

Comment: Returns different values with different page zoom. Win7, Opera, FF.

Comment: `position: absolute` on the `div` assigned to variable `outer`, as well as `left` and `top`, are doing nothing and can be removed. They will only have effect if `body { position: relative; }` is set. Also it is completely pointless to affix a value of `0` with `px`.

Comment: Note that I got a width of 0.0003 in my mobile Chrome, beware of comparing to zero, better do something like `>= 1`.

Answer (score 85):

Using jQuery, you can shorten Matthew Vines answer to:

```
function getScrollBarWidth () {
    var $outer = $('<div>').css({visibility: 'hidden', width: 100, overflow: 'scroll'}).appendTo('body'),
        widthWithScroll = $('<div>').css({width: '100%'}).appendTo($outer).outerWidth();
    $outer.remove();
    return 100 - widthWithScroll;
};
```

Comment: Would this solution really feel cleaner if the entire source code for JQuery was copy pasted before it? Because that's pretty much what this solution is doing.

This question did not ask for an answer in JQuery, and it is perfectly possible and efficient to perform this task without the use of a library.

Comment: If you are already using JQuery, then Daemon's comment is irrelevant. Yes, to add JQuery just to do this would be nonsense, but to those already using JQuery in their project, this is a much 'simpler' solution than the accepted one.

Answer (score 31):

For me, the most useful way was

```
(window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth)
```

with vanilla JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: Just what I needed. One suggestion: The second term can be replaced with `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. `documentElement` more clearly and cleanly expresses the intention of getting the `<html>` element.

Comment: best, simplest solution if your using JS!

Comment: This gives `0` if the window does not already have a vertical scrollbar. This may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 26):

This is only script I've found, which is working in webkit browsers ... :)

```
$.scrollbarWidth = function() {
  var parent, child, width;

  if(width===undefined) {
    parent = $('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:auto"><div/></div>').appendTo('body');
    child=parent.children();
    width=child.innerWidth()-child.height(99).innerWidth();
    parent.remove();
  }

 return width;
};
```

Minimized version:

```
$.scrollbarWidth=function(){var a,b,c;if(c===undefined){a=$('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:auto"><div/></div>').appendTo('body');b=a.children();c=b.innerWidth()-b.height(99).innerWidth();a.remove()}return c};
```

And you have to call it when document is ready ... so

```
$(function(){ console.log($.scrollbarWidth()); });
```

Tested 2012-03-28 on Windows 7 in latest FF, Chrome, IE & Safari and 100% working.

source: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#scrollbarwidth

Comment: Returns different values with different page zoom. Win7, Opera, FF.

Comment: width will ALWAYS === undefined in that code. might as well do if (true) { ... }

Comment: Correction: `width` will _always_ === undefined the **first** time the function is called. On subsequent calls to the function `width` is already set, that check just prevents the calculations being run again needlessly.

Comment: @MartinAnsty But the [width] variable is declared *inside* the function, therefore it's recreated every time you call the function.

Comment: @MadSkunk you're quite right, my mistake. In that case the if statement either is doing nothing or serves some other purpose that eludes me.

Comment: @MartinAnsty, if you look at the [source](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-misc/blob/master/jquery.ba-scrollbarwidth.js#L12), it's declared in the outer closure.

Comment: Just to reinforce the point made by @sstur and @TheCloudlessSky, the code above is _not_ the same as the one in Ben Alman's plugin, and it will not cache the result in `width`, but rather recalculate it every single time. It works, but it is terribly inefficient. Please do the world a favour and use the [correct version](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-misc/blob/master/jquery.ba-scrollbarwidth.js) in Alman's plugin instead.

Answer (score 26):

if you are looking for a simple operation, just mix plain dom js and jquery,

```
var swidth=(window.innerWidth-$(window).width());
```

returns the size of current page scrollbar. (if it is visible or else will return 0)

Comment: This will fail in case that the window didn't have scrollbars(big monitor, or small page/app)

Comment: this is perfectly what I wanted

Comment: For those of us who don't use jQuery, what does `$(element).width()` do?  How can that be written without jQuery?

Answer (score 18):

```
window.scrollBarWidth = function() {
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; 
  var width = document.body.clientWidth;
  document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll'; 
  width -= document.body.clientWidth; 
  if(!width) width = document.body.offsetWidth - document.body.clientWidth;
  document.body.style.overflow = ''; 
  return width; 
}
```

Comment: First tried the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes#answer-986977) but found that that did no longer work in Firefox on Windows 8. Switched to this variant that does the job beautifully.

Comment: Shorter code, but the browser has to redraw the whole page, so it is very slow.

Answer (score 9):

I found a simple solution that works for elements inside of the page, instead of the page itself:
`$('#element')[0].offsetHeight - $('#element')[0].clientHeight`

This returns the height of the x-axis scrollbar.

Comment: Great one!! You made my day :) It's working as well with ".offsetWidth" and ".clientWidth" for y-axis scrollbars.

Comment: Doesn't seem entirely reliable, unfortunately, at least for widths. .clientWidth seems to include half the scrollbar's width in both FireFox and Chrome under Linux.

Answer (score 8):

From [David Walsh's blog](https://davidwalsh.name/detect-scrollbar-width):

```js
// Create the measurement node
var scrollDiv = document.createElement("div");
scrollDiv.className = "scrollbar-measure";
document.body.appendChild(scrollDiv);

// Get the scrollbar width
var scrollbarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth;
console.info(scrollbarWidth); // Mac:  15

// Delete the DIV 
document.body.removeChild(scrollDiv);
```

```css
.scrollbar-measure {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 overflow: scroll;
 position: absolute;
 top: -9999px;
}
```

Gives me 17 on my website, 14 here on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick, no?

```
function getScrollbarWidth() {
  return (window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can determine `window` scroll bar with `document` as below using jquery + javascript:

```
var scrollbarWidth = ($(document).width() - window.innerWidth);
console.info("Window Scroll Bar Width=" + scrollbarWidth );
```

Comment: Note that innerWidth is for IE9+. Otherwise great solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have an element with scrollbars on it use:

```
function getScrollbarHeight(el) {
    return el.getBoundingClientRect().height - el.scrollHeight;
};
```

If there is no horzintscrollbar present the function will retun 0

Comment: This is the best answer yet. K.I.S.S. rules all

Answer (score 4):

Create an empty `div` and make sure it's present on all pages (i.e. by putting it in the `header` template).

Give it this styling:

```
#scrollbar-helper {
    // Hide it beyond the borders of the browser
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;

    // Make sure the scrollbar is always visible
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Then simply check for the size of `#scrollbar-helper` with Javascript:

```
var scrollbarWidth = document.getElementById('scrollbar-helper').offsetWidth;
var scrollbarHeight = document.getElementById('scrollbar-helper').offsetHeight;
```

No need to calculate anything, as this `div` will always have the `width` and `height` of the `scrollbar`.

The only downside is that there will be an empty `div` in your templates.. But on the other hand, your Javascript files will be cleaner, as this only takes 1 or 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

```
function getScrollBarWidth() {
    return window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth;
}
```

Most of the browser use 15px for the scrollbar width

Comment: of course, this only works if the scrollbar is already visible. Sometimes we need to predict size before it is shown. Also, mobile browsers don't use 15px for scroll bar.

Answer (score 3):

The way `Antiscroll.js` does it in it's code is:

```
function scrollbarSize () {
  var div = $(
      '<div class="antiscroll-inner" style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow-y:scroll;'
    + 'position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"><div style="height:100px;width:100%"/>'
    + '</div>'
  );

  $('body').append(div);
  var w1 = $(div).innerWidth();
  var w2 = $('div', div).innerWidth();
  $(div).remove();

  return w1 - w2;
};
```

The code is from here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/antiscroll/blob/master/antiscroll.js#L447

Answer (score 3):

```
detectScrollbarWidthHeight: function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.overflow = "scroll";
    div.style.visibility = "hidden";
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.width = '100px';
    div.style.height = '100px';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    return {
        width: div.offsetWidth - div.clientWidth,
        height: div.offsetHeight - div.clientHeight
    };
},
```

Tested in Chrome, FF, IE8, IE11.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that solution in the `material-ui` code and it works for me.

```
const scrollbarWidth = window.innerWidth -  document.querySelector('body').clientWidth;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way I could think of is:

```
const scrollWidth = element.offsetWidth - element.clientWidth;
```

If there is no scrollbar, it will return 0.

Comment: This applies to scrollbar within the element which may be customized by [`element::webkit-scrollbar`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/).

Answer (score 1):

```
function getWindowScrollBarHeight() {
    let bodyStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
    let fullHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
    let contentsHeight = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    let marginTop = parseInt(bodyStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-top'), 10);
    let marginBottom = parseInt(bodyStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'), 10);
    return fullHeight - contentHeight - marginTop - marginBottom;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery (only tested in firefox):

```
function getScrollBarHeight() {
    var jTest = $('<div style="display:none;width:50px;overflow: scroll"><div style="width:100px;"><br /><br /></div></div>');
    $('body').append(jTest);
    var h = jTest.innerHeight();
    jTest.css({
        overflow: 'auto',
        width: '200px'
    });
    var h2 = jTest.innerHeight();
    return h - h2;
}

function getScrollBarWidth() {
    var jTest = $('<div style="display:none;height:50px;overflow: scroll"><div style="height:100px;"></div></div>');
    $('body').append(jTest);
    var w = jTest.innerWidth();
    jTest.css({
        overflow: 'auto',
        height: '200px'
    });
    var w2 = jTest.innerWidth();
    return w - w2;
}
```

But I actually like @Steve's answer better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/986977/5914609

However in my case it did not work. And i spent hours searching for the solution.
Finally i've returned to above code and added !important to each style. And it worked.
I can not add comments below the original answer. So here is the fix:

```
function getScrollBarWidth () {
  var inner = document.createElement('p');
  inner.style.width = "100% !important";
  inner.style.height = "200px !important";

  var outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.style.position = "absolute !important";
  outer.style.top = "0px !important";
  outer.style.left = "0px !important";
  outer.style.visibility = "hidden !important";
  outer.style.width = "200px !important";
  outer.style.height = "150px !important";
  outer.style.overflow = "hidden !important";
  outer.appendChild (inner);

  document.body.appendChild (outer);
  var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll !important';
  var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
  if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

  document.body.removeChild (outer);

  return (w1 - w2);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This life-hack decision will give you opportunity to find **browser scrollY width** (vanilla JavaScript). Using this example you can get scrollY width **on any element** including those elements that shouldn't have to have scroll according to your current design conception,:

```
getComputedScrollYWidth     (el)  {

  let displayCSSValue  ; // CSS value
  let overflowYCSSValue; // CSS value

  // SAVE current original STYLES values
  {
    displayCSSValue   = el.style.display;
    overflowYCSSValue = el.style.overflowY;
  }

  // SET TEMPORALLY styles values
  {
    el.style.display   = 'block';
    el.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
  }

  // SAVE SCROLL WIDTH of the current browser.
  const scrollWidth = el.offsetWidth - el.clientWidth;

  // REPLACE temporally STYLES values by original
  {
    el.style.display   = displayCSSValue;
    el.style.overflowY = overflowYCSSValue;
  }

  return scrollWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the more concise and easy to read solution based on offset width difference:

```typescript
function getScrollbarWidth(): number {

  // Creating invisible container
  const outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll'; // forcing scrollbar to appear
  outer.style.msOverflowStyle = 'scrollbar'; // needed for WinJS apps
  document.body.appendChild(outer);

  // Creating inner element and placing it in the container
  const inner = document.createElement('div');
  outer.appendChild(inner);

  // Calculating difference between container's full width and the child width
  const scrollbarWidth = (outer.offsetWidth - inner.offsetWidth);

  // Removing temporary elements from the DOM
  outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);

  return scrollbarWidth;

}
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slavafomin/tsrmgcu9/).

Answer (score 0):

Already coded in my library so here it is:

```
var vScrollWidth = window.screen.width - window.document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

I should mention that jQuery `$(window).width()` can also be used instead of `window.document.documentElement.clientWidth`.

It doesn't work if you open developer tools in firefox on the right but it overcomes it if the devs window is opened at bottom!

`window.screen` is supported [quirksmode.org](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html)!

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work, but maybe there is a simpler solution that works in all browsers?

```js
// Create the measurement node
var scrollDiv = document.createElement("div");
scrollDiv.className = "scrollbar-measure";
document.body.appendChild(scrollDiv);

// Get the scrollbar width
var scrollbarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth;
console.info(scrollbarWidth); // Mac:  15

// Delete the DIV 
document.body.removeChild(scrollDiv);
```

```css
.scrollbar-measure {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 overflow: scroll;
 position: absolute;
 top: -9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an updated version of @Matthew Vines answer.

It's easier to read, easier to understand. It doesn't require an inner element. The element created to get the scroll bar width has a 100% height/width so it doesn't create any visible scroll bar on the body on lower end PCs/mobiles which could take a bit more time to create the element, get the widths, and finally remove the element.

```js
const getScrollBarWidth = () => {
  const e = document.createElement('div');
  Object.assign(e.style, {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    overflow: 'scroll',
    position: 'absolute',
    visibility: 'hidden',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
  });

  document.body.appendChild(e);

  const scrollbarWidth = e.offsetWidth - e.clientWidth;

  document.body.removeChild(e);

  return scrollbarWidth;
};

console.log(getScrollBarWidth());
```

I do recommend to check for the scroll bar width only once, at page load (except if it doesn't fit your needs) then store the result in a state/variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution to find the scrollbar width of any element inside the webpage rather than the webpage itself. You can also rewrite it to work for scrollbar height in the case of horizontal scrolbars by replacing its width related properties with their height related counterparts.

The `offsetWidth` property returns the total width of content, padding, border, and scrollbar (if there is any). Whereas, `clientWidth` property returns only the total width of content and padding.

So, if we substract `clientWidth` and horizontal border from `offsetWidth`, we will be left with the width of the scrollbar. That is to say, if there is any scrollbar, we will get the width of the scrollbar. But if there isn't any scrollbar, we will get `0`.

```
const element = document.querySelector("div");
const elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
const horizontalBorder = parseFloat(elementStyle.borderLeftWidth) + parseFloat(elementStyle.borderRightWidth);
const scrollbarWidth = element.offsetWidth - element.clientWidth - horizontalBorder + "px";
```