# How can I disable a browser or element scrollbar, but still allow scrolling with wheel or arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, scrollbar

I want to hide any scrollbars from my `div` elements and my whole `body`, but still let the user scroll with the mouse wheel or arrow keys. How can this be achieved with raw JavaScript or jQuery? Any ideas?

Comment: I answered the same here on this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16671476/1577396). I hope it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: https://github.com/lsvx/hide-bars

Answer (score 49):

Like the previous answers, you would use `overflow:hidden` to disable the scrollbars on the body/div.

Then you'd bind the `mousewheel` event to a function that would change the `scrollTop` of the div to emulate scrolling.

For arrow keys, you would bind the `keydown` event to recognize an arrow key, and then change `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` of the div as appropriate to emulate scrolling.
(Note: you use `keydown` instead of `keypress` since IE doesn't recognize `keypress` for arrow keys.)
**Edit:** I couldn't get FF/Chrome to recognize `keydown` on a div, but it works in IE8. Depending on what you needed this for, you can set a `keydown` listener on the `document` to scroll the div. (Check out the keyCode reference as an example.)

For example, scrolling with the mouse wheel (using jQuery and a mousewheel plugin):

```
<div id="example" style="width:300px;height:200px;overflow:hidden">
insert enough text to overflow div here
</div>

<script>
$("#example").bind("mousewheel",function(ev, delta) {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $(this).scrollTop(scrollTop-Math.round(delta));
});
</script>
```

(This is a quick mockup, you'd have to adjust the numbers since for me, this scrolls a bit slowly.)

[keyCode reference](http://www.ryancooper.com/resources/keycode.asp)
[mousewheel plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel)
[keydown, keypress @ quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)

**Update 12/19/2012:**

The updated location of the mousewheel plugin is at: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work if you want to hide the scrollbars on the BODY, and then bind the mousewheel to body scroll.

Comment: @DavidBarnes hm looks like a lot of things got outdated after 3 years.  I had to get the updated mousewheel plugin from github, and to get scrolling to work, I had to bind to document instead of body. here's my example: http://pastebin.com/U08b6MCx

Comment: comment from @radry: _The solution suggested in the top answer doesn't work anymore, even the "update" comment doesn't. At least my mousewheel does nothing. How to solve this in the year 2014?_

Answer (score 12):

What about a purely CSS solution?

**Solution 1** (cross browser but more hacky)

```css
#div {
  position: fixed;
  right: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 5em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="div">
    Scrolling div with hidden scrollbars!<br/>
    On overflow, this div will scroll with the mousewheel but scrollbars won't be visible.<br/>
    Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Solution 2** (uses experimental features, may not support some browsers)

Just add the `nobars` class to any element you want to hide the scrollbars on.

```
.nobars {
    /* Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width */
    scrollbar-width: none;
    /* IE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx */
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.nobars::-webkit-scrollbar {
    /* Chrome/Edge/Opera/Safari: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ */
    display: none;
}
```

**Solution 3** (cross browser javascript)

**[Perfect Scrollbar](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar)** doesn't require jQuery (although it can utilise jQuery if installed) and has a [demo available here](https://perfectscrollbar.com/). The components can be styled with css such as in the following example:

```
.ps__rail-y {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Here is a complete example including the implementation of Perfect Scrollbar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/perfect-scrollbar.css">
<style>
  #container {
    position: relative; /* can be absolute or fixed if required */
    height: 200px; /* any value will do */
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .ps__rail-y {
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>
<script src='dist/perfect-scrollbar.min.js'></script>

<div id="container">
  Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>Scrollable<br>
</div>

<script>
  // on dom ready...
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var ps = new PerfectScrollbar(container);
  //ps.update(container);
  //ps.destroy(container);
</script>
```

Comment: I see what you mean. You could create a background behind it separately to fix this problem and make it the same size as the scrolling <div>.

Comment: It seems like `-moz-scrollbars-none` actually disables scrolling. Or is there a way to combine it with `overflow:auto` somehow?

Comment: This used to work, presumably that's no longer the case. Looks like Javascript is the only option until this is added to Firefox :(

Comment: @phreakhead Added a 3rd method, which relies on JS but not jQuery. The other solutions may still be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 8):

You dont have to use jquery or js to make this. Its more performant with simple webkit.

Just add the code below to your css file.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Caution !
This will disable all the scrollbar so be sure to put it in a specific class or id if you just want one to be hidden.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't work in other browsers. As far as I'm aware, currently, only webkit browsers allow customizing scrollbars. Do you know a cross-browser solution like this?

Comment: @TheLightSabrix you may be interested in [my IE, Chrome and Firefox answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13500027/1476989) above (see solution 2). I didn't bother researching any other browsers, comment if you'd like me to try any in particular.

Answer (score 7):

I much prefer SamGoody's answer provided to a duplicate of this question. It leaves native scrolling effects intact, instead of trying to manually re-implement for a few particular input devices:

> A better solution is to set the target div to overflow:scroll, and wrap it inside a second element that is 8px narrower, who's overflow:hidden.

See the [original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3253396/179583) for a fleshed-out example. You may want to use JavaScript to [determine the actual size of scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/javascript-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes) rather than assuming they are always 8px wide as his example does.

Comment: Great suggestion, but not for Mac, as they don't have scrollbars

Answer (score 4):

To get this working for me, I used this CSS:

```
html { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

But I had problems using `$(this).scrollTop()`, so I bound to my #id, but adjusted the scrollTop of window.  Also, my smooth scrolling mouse would fire lots of 1 or -1 deltas, so I multiplied that by 20.

```
$("#example").bind("mousewheel", function (ev, delta) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop - Math.round(delta * 20));
});
```

Comment: Awesome. In my case, it was `overflow-x: hidden` that I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As **Baldráni** said above

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }
```

Or you can do

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{ width: 0px; }
```

(posted for other people that stumble on this from google search!)

Answer (score -4):

Well, perhaps not the most intuitive in my opinion, but I can imagine you being able to make it a decent experience, give this a try.

```
overflow:hidden;
```

make sure the parent object has a `height` and `width`, and displays as `block`