# Scroll website with mouse wheel, not drag to scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I've built this website based off a template where you drag to scroll through the photos but due to a change of requirements I need to change it so you just scroll a mouse wheel to scroll like normal website do.

Any idea from the code how this is done?

Not even sure if it's wholly CSS or JS.

http://www.replyonline.co.uk/DirectionGroup/xmas/index.php

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using JavaScript - specifically [jQuery Kinetic](http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/) by the looks of it.

If you turn off JavaScript (or remove the script from the page), it scrolls like a 'normal' page.

**EDIT :**

Outside of the Kinetic plugin (didn't look where), the script is changing the `overflow` CSS to `hidden`; this needs to remain as `scroll`, as per the inital state of the page *sans* JavaScript.

```
.ib-main-wrapper {
    bottom: 24px;
    left: 18px;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: -98px;
    margin-top: 115px;
    outline: medium none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Just removed the jQuery Kinetic script from the page, it removed the ability to drag but still no scroll

Nothing in the CSS for #ib-main-wrapper or #ib-main is it?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you question is based on this

[Remove HTML scrollbars but allow mousewheel scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253199/remove-html-scrollbars-but-allow-mousewheel-scrolling)

which points to this

[How can I disable a browser or element scrollbar, but still allow scrolling with wheel or arrow keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326570/how-to-disable-browser-or-element-scrollbar-but-let-scrolling-with-wheel-or-arr)