# Scroll without a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, textarea, scrollbar, overflow

Sample form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
* {font:13px arial; color:white;}
body {background:black;}
label {display:inline-block; width:50px;}
input, textarea {margin:0; border:1px solid red; padding:0; background:green;}
textarea {width:300px; height:100px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
<div><label for="entry_0">Name</label><input type="text" id="entry_0"></div>
<div><label for="entry_1">Email</label><input type="text" id="entry_1"></div>
<div><label for="entry_2">URL</label><input type="text" id="entry_2"></div>
<div id="parent"><textarea id="entry_3"></textarea></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to remove/hide the textarea scrollbar as it doesn't match my form style. I know I can use jQuery plugins to style the scrollbar, but they don't work reliably across different browsers/systems.
To hide the scrollbar I can use `textarea {width:300px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;}`, but it completely stops Firefox scrolling through mouse and keyboard.
I also tried the following workaround:

```
#parent {width:284px; height:102px; overflow:hidden;}
textarea {width:300px; height:100px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;}
```

It should work accurately if I add some script to calculate the parent division width:

```
var textareaWidth = document.getElementById('entry_3').scrollWidth;
document.getElementById('parent').style.width = textareaWidth + 'px';
```

But anyhow the above approach doesn't seem to work in Chrome/Safari.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RainLover/snTaP/

Open the above demo in Chrome/Safari >> insert some text into the textarea >> highlight/select a line and drag your mouse to the right and you'll see the scrollbar. Or use the keyboard keys `Page Up` and `Page Down`.

Any corrections or other solutions?

Comment: unrelated to the question, but in your example code, you should just put these styles (`font:13px arial; color:white;`) on `body` rather than `*`. They will "cascade" down, without the performance hit of using `*`

Comment: Then the text fields wouldn't inherit the body style.

Comment: Strange, I didn't know that.  All the same, you should probably not use `*` and use `body, input, textarea {...}` or some such thing

Comment: You should declare your doctype, like this it'll cause issues.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820304/hidden-scrollbars-in-firefox-allows-scrolling-but-just-no-scrollbar for the right answer.

Comment: I've already seen that. It doesn't help. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacky but seems to work...

**Using `::after` pseudoelement**

```
#parent {width:302px; overflow:hidden; position: relative;}
textarea {width:300px; height:100px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;}
textarea:focus {
    outline-offset: 0;
    outline-style: none;
}

#parent::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    height: 102px;
    border-left:1px solid red;
    background-color: black;
    content: "";
    display: block;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/snTaP/3/

**OR using additional div**

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <textarea id="entry_3"></textarea>
  <div id="hidescroll"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {width:302px; overflow:hidden; position: relative;}
textarea {width:300px; height:100px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;}
textarea:focus {
    outline-offset: 0;
    outline-style: none;
}
#hidescroll {
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 102px;
    border-left:1px solid red;
    background-color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/snTaP/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But in my real form I have a background image, not black color. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sure! Here you go: [Sample demo with background image](http://jsfiddle.net/RainLover/snTaP/9/)

Comment: Well, simply use the same background-image and align it with background-position.
http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/snTaP/10/

`background-position: -283px -53px;`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! There's just one thing I couldn't figure out: how did you calculate the `background-position` values  and how can I check the `console.log`?

Comment: Print Screen + image editor. :)
To check console.log in Chrome, IE9+, FF (with Firebug installed): press F12, open 'Console' tab.