# Hide scrollbars in an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I tried to hide scrollbars in an iframe whose content is loaded from an external website.
I used `overflow:hidden` and also `overflow-x: hidden` as well as `overflow-y: hidden` but that doesnt seem to solve my problem

What did I do wrong? Or what is wrong with my approach?

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zacpnu4g/)

Here is my **HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="noScrolling">
    <iframe scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" class="inner" src="https://www.initialstate.com/embed/#/tiles/kkCIxiV4PJmg6y88ldn5HvhNiALMBdHp" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.outer {
  position: relative;
  background: url("http://wrb.farm/demo/background-with-backdrop.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.noScrolling {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 54%;
  height: 73%;
  top: 9%;
  left: 23%;
  overflow: hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Scrollbars are from the Element

```
<div class="gap row" data-ng-class="{edit:app.editMode, auto: autoLayout}">
```

Wich is inside the iFrame, and not the iFrame itself. 
So you would have to change the style of this element (`overflow:hidden`)

Comment: I know that one :) But lets say we dont have control over external css. But hey, thank you.

Comment: If you don't have control over it, you can't avoid inner Elements to do what their style is set to do :/

Comment: @KilvishShakal what you can do however, if you know the element, you can get it via JavaScript and change its styles. Would that be good for you?

Comment: With javascript do I have to disable scrolling of that element? Moreover, will it override?

Comment: You can avoid it to have scrollbars by `ELEMENT.style.overflow = "hidden"`

Comment: But then, the div wont scroll. I was looking for a way to disable scrollbar and not scrolling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98492/discussion-between-kilvish-shakal-and-codeisir).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752641/scroll-without-a-scrollbar