# Scroll div content without scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have two different views. I don't want to display scroller for the internal div. By varying the external div scroller only I have to vary the content in the inner div. But both are different view pages.

I want similar operation to this (from http://jsfiddle.net/qcv5Q/1/):
In the main page(main div) I have defined like

```
$(window).scroll(function()    {
    document.getElementById("mainDiv").contentWindow.callchildPage();
});
```

In the child page I have called this function,I dont know how to code here to show as in fiddle?

Comment: Hey Charan, you have already collected 21 questions, you should already know that you should be a bit more specific and detailed while asking your questions. We like code. Show something

Comment: I am not sure why you don't use similar code as the one in the fiddle you attached? If that's what you are after I mean? Or what do you mean with 'two divs are in two different pages'?

Comment: Pretty confused as to what this question is actually asking

Comment: @charan ,is it what you trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/qcv5Q/162/

Comment: sorry for that,actually I have copied the link but it was not properly copied.In the outer div(main page ) I have given like $(window).scroll(function () {       document.getElementById("mainDiv").contentWindow.callchildPage();
            });

Comment: I have fixed the formatting of that line of code in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326570/how-to-disable-browser-or-element-scrollbar-but-allow-scrolling-with-wheel-or-a

Answer (score 0):

### ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/qcv5Q/200/)***

Just set the scroller to be relative to the sidebar content by using

```
#scroller{ width: 150%; }
```

The demo shows how the scrollbar will not show even at varying widths.