# Hidding scrollbar but not stoping scrolling

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to hide scroll bar, but still leaving option of scrolling up/down?
I try overflow: hidden;
It removes scroll bar but i can not scroll.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable a browser or element scrollbar, but still allow scrolling with wheel or arrow keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326570/how-can-i-disable-a-browser-or-element-scrollbar-but-still-allow-scrolling-with) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: i asked if can be done by css, and specify on only one div.

Comment: The second link has a CSS-only answer. For the record, nothing in your question says it must be a CSS-only answer. Tags are for sorting. http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/954/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q73aomrk/)

MARKUP:

```
<section>
   <article>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
   </article>
</section>
```

STYLE:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section{
    width:480px;
    height:320px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
article{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 40px 20px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without plugins:

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="scrollable"> ... ... ... </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#scrollable {
   height: 150px;   
   width: 218px; /* #content.width + 18px */
   overflow-y: scroll;    
}
```

However, there are a lot of jquery library's that enables a lot of nice extra's

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is certainly possible and fairly easy. Lets say we have two divs named `inner-div` and `outer-div`:

```
.outer-div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-div {
    width: 215px; //Width of it's parent + 15px (the average width of a scrollbar)
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

The `inner-div` is a little bit wider then the outer-div (15 pixels). The `outer-div` has the property `overflow: hidden;`. The scrollbar will be invisible because it falls just outside of `outer-div`, but you will still be able to scroll. I didn't test it, but you get the idea.