# How to get the dimensions of the scroll bars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript : Get the browser's scrollbar sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/javascript-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes)

I have an HTML table that contains lots of rows and columns. Therefore, it has vertical and horizontal scroll bars.

How can I get the dimensions in pixels of these scroll bars in Javascript/jQuerys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben Alman has a nice [scrollbarWidth plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#scrollbarwidth) that works nicely.

```
var content = $('#content').css( 'width', 'auto' ),
  container = content.parent();

if ( content.height() > container.height() ) {
  content.width( content.width() - $.scrollbarWidth() );
}
```