# Div scrollbars in mac webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, macos

I have one div inside another. The inner div is larger than the outer div, and I want the outer div to scroll to show the hidden content. I marked it as overflow: auto and it works fine.

However, I also need scrollbars to appear on the outer div due to business constraints. This works in all browsers on Windows. It also works in Firefox on Mac. On Safari/Chrome on Mac I expect to see the scrollbars appear when I scroll the div's content, just like they do when I scroll any web page. What happens instead is that I can scroll the content but scrollbars never appear. What do I have to do to get scrollbars to show up properly?

Here's what I have:

```
<style type="text/css">
.inner {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">asdf qwer qwer asdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `overflow: scroll;` work?

Comment: @Brendan no, it doesn't. A fiddle for his example. http://jsfiddle.net/yxAzA/

Comment: They appear when I scroll (Mac/Chrome)

Comment: Is this questions answer relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7855592/600101 *I edited the link to go directly to the answer*.

Comment: I was going to add what @HenrikAmmer said as an answer. The other option is to plug a mouse into the Mac :)

Comment: @Quentin For me (Lion/Safari or Lion/Chrome) the scrollbars do not appear when scrolling at all. Screenshot taken while scrolling. http://cl.ly/image/26212n1a241b

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing scroll bars from being hidden for MacOS trackpad users in WebKit/Blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/preventing-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-macos-trackpad-users-in-webkit-blin)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wasn't able to sort out why... but I went @HenrikAmmer's answer. That's good enough for my solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think overflow:scroll; will work .