# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch breaks my -webkit-scrollbar css in iOS

Tags: ios, css, scroll, webkit

This code works great for styling scrollbars:

```
.frame::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #000;
}
.frame::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 6px;
}
.frame::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #000;
}
.frame::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #333;
}
```

But everytime i want to make it touch enabled (for easing in the mobile scrolling), all scrollbars disappear

```
.frame {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Any solution to keep the scrollbar in iOS or mobiles?

Comment: http://patrickmuff.ch/blog/2014/10/01/how-we-fixed-the-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-bug-on-ios/

Comment: [Here's the bug report.](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137043) Comment to let Apple know it's important to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either custom style your scrollbars with css for webkit browsers or enable

```
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Both of them doesnt work together in latest safaris. If you put both only touch will work. Tested in Iphone 5 and 6