# iOS: any way to make -webkit-overflow-scrolling and ::-webkit-scrollbar work together?

Tags: ios, css, webkit, scrollbar, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to apply custom styles to the scrollbars (actually, trying to make scrollbars always visible) *and* preserve the momentum scrolling for the iOS app:

```
#container {
    height: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #000;
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 6px;
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #000;
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #333;
}
```

But `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` and `::-webkit-scrollbar` styles don't work together.
There's already a related question on StackOverflow:

[-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch breaks my -webkit-scrollbar css in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871556/webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-breaks-my-webkit-scrollbar-css-in-ios)

So, from the height of spring'2016, is there any way to have a momentum scrolling while styling the scrollbars at the same time? I'm ready to ditch the `-WebKit-overflow-scrolling: touch` if there's another method that can fake it.

Please don't suggest using niceScroll, iScroll, etc. - I've tried these; actually, I'm currently using one of such scripts and want to get away from it.

Comment: [Here's the bug report.](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137043) Comment to let Apple know it's important to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch breaks my -webkit-scrollbar css in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871556/webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-breaks-my-webkit-scrollbar-css-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned in the thread linked above, `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` is not compatible with your `-webkit-scrollbar` properties. If you don't want to download a 3rd party scroller, you will have to write some custom JS to get the functionality you're looking for.