# Is it possible to force a scrollbar on iPad?

Tags: css, ipad

I know the scrollbar/two fingers/one finger theme has been covered here before, but that was from the point of view of actually scrolling.

Scrollbars perform another important function which is to *indicate to the user that there is more to see*. Is there a native way to do this on iPad?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/how-can-i-prevent-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-os-x-trackpad-users-in-webki

Comment: The link would appear to be OSX Lion specific. The suggested css doesn't seem to work on iPad.

Comment: Doesn't iOS flash the scrollbar automatically even on Safari?

Comment: Okay - I've got that to work now. The iPad was cacheing like there was no tomorrow. Thanks.