# Select2: Adding an indicator to show more results (On a Mac)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

On a Windows machine the Select2 component shows a scrollbar when there are more results available than fit in the dropdown menu.

On a Mac, the UX isn't as good. The scrollbar won't show until the user starts scrolling.

So, is there a good way to show the user there are more results (on a Mac)? I don't want a link that says "Show All" that navigates to another page. What I'd like is to alert the user that they should scroll to see all the results.

I believe that on a Mac that scrollbars don't normally show by default so it's not readily apparent when a user has to scroll.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated; thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/how-can-i-prevent-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-os-x-trackpad-users-in-webki

Answer (score 1):

If you implement custom scrollbars with something like [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) you can effectively force scrollbars to appear.