# Scroll bar not visible in Safari w/ overflow-y: scroll

Tags: html, css

When having a `fixed` element that has `overflow: auto` or `scroll` contained in a `body` element that has `overflow: hidden`, in Safari 8.0.x the scroll bar is not visible, but the element still scrolls. In Firefox 41.0.x the scroll bar is visible.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz872481/2/) that shows the behavior.

Is there any way to keep the scroll bar visible in Safari?

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    max-height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: lightblue;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content-a {
    background: yellow;
    height: 900px;
}

.main {
    background: grey;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 10px;
}

.content-b {
    height: 200px;
}

body, .main {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="content-a">
        content
    </div>
    bottom
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="content-b">
        content
    </div>
    bottom
</div>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/how-can-i-prevent-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-os-x-trackpad-users-in-webki

Comment: I tried your code in my Safari 8.0.8 (OSX Yosemite) and it's perfectly working.

Comment: @Enzo you can see the scrollbar?

Comment: Yes @Quoid, I have it on the right, allowing me to scroll the yellow sidebar

Comment: @Enzo weird, I can't see it on the fiddle or local code

Comment: @Quoid Did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to stylize it and force it show:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(100,100,100,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

**WORKING EDIT:**

```css
.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: inherit;
}

.sidebar:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

.sidebar:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}

.sidebar:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(100,100,100,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: this is similar to what [Radio](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3311552/radio) [posted above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/how-can-i-prevent-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-os-x-trackpad-users-in-webki), except it's scoped to the whole doc rather than the `element` (which would probably be better), but what I *don't* like is that it doesn't auto hide the scrollbar like the default browser behavior

Comment: that's odd, that is default safari behavior, perhaps that is also why you can see the scrollbar