# Prevent scroll from hiding on iPhone or Ipad

Tags: css, scroll, responsive-design

I am wondering how I am able to prevent hiding scroll bars for my responsive web application.

If it is possible I would like to use pure CSS for this.

**Code example**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
        height: 11px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: 2px solid white; /* should match background, can't be transparent */
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
        background-color: #fff; 
        border-radius: 8px; 
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know can I call your post as duplicate?, however I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/how-can-i-prevent-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-os-x-trackpad-users-in-webki) is answer of your question.

Comment: Can you add the code and a working demo?

Comment: @alirezasafian [That](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/how-can-i-prevent-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-os-x-trackpad-users-in-webki) is a question concerning Mac OSX (desktop/laptop OS), the OP's question involves it's evil cousin iOS (mobile OS). Although it's not much of a question without  some code....