# Scrollbar is different depending on where I am

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos

I am developing a website using html, css, and javascript. I use a Mac.

When I view the webpage in one location the scrollbars for the divs and the page itself always appear (always-on scrollbars). However, when I view the same webpage from home on the same computer, the scrollbars are the fading scrollbars from OSX Lion and don't show up upon opening page. The user can still scroll and the scrollbars show up when you are scrolling, but disappear once you take your hand off the mouse.

This is a problem for me, because I want the user to know that they can scroll.

I know I can fix it for myself in Preferences, but is there a way to make sure that the scrollbars are always-on for the user? And does anyone know why the location would have this affect??

Any help is appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/preventing-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-macos-trackpad-users-in-webkit-blin

Comment: OMG its the trackpad! I use a mouse at work. Thank you so much! I looked for something on Stack Overflow for forever, but could not find anything. I guess I did not look hard enough ;)