# Making the main scrollbar always visible - without scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a section of text that I want to always show the vertical scrollbar handle even before the user has scrolled. I've read the answer is

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

However that does not seem to initially show the scroll bar. It only shows it once the user has started scrolling. How would I show it always regardless if they have started scrolling or not? Is this possible?

Thanks!

JS fiddle for example of it not showing before scroll:

https://jsfiddle.net/5k59dxjy/

Comment: It appears to work fine in chrome. What browser are you having issues in?

Comment: Chrome. Haha. Can you see it BEFORE scroll?

Comment: I see it immediately upon load.

Comment: We'll thats very strange. I see nothing until its scrolled

Comment: @JDDavis Mac or PC?

Comment: My test machine is windows, but I can check from within MacOS as well

Comment: Hmm. I'm on Mac and do not see it. Also don't see it on iOS

Comment: Please view [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/preventing-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-macos-trackpad-users-in-webkit-blin). It seems to address your issue in MacOS

Comment: @JDDavis That did it! Now it works on Mac and iOS. Thank you. Type that as an answer and I'll accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior works as expected on Windows machines, but it appears MacOS and iOS have their own handling of scrollbars. You can see this issue addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/preventing-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-macos-trackpad-users-in-webkit-blin).

Some of the options listed within the answer are to style the scrollbar manually like so:

```
.frame::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 11px;
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white; /* should match background, can't be transparent */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
    background-color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 8px; 
}
```

You can also use javascript to manually scroll the scrollbar on page load, just a single pixel. Like this:

```
$('#scrollable-section').scrollTop(1).scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help JD!