# How to show scrollbar in a table in Mac OS?

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I am not able to show the scrollbar (in Safari) when container size is smaller than a table. In this case, a horizontal scrollbar should get added to the table.

I've create the example fiddle ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/1zpudt21/2/)) which is showing the horizontal scrollbar in Chrome and Firefox.

```
table {
  width:100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border:solid 2px;

}
tr, td{
   border:solid 1px;
}
tbody{
      overflow-x: auto !important;
    display: block !important;
}
```

I followed the solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/preventing-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-macos-trackpad-users-in-webkit-blin) question for Mac but still no luck.

***Safari: V10.1***

Please note that I can only add styles to the table, tbody etc, not to the upper container div.

Comment: Which version of Safari? I get a scrollbar in your fiddle in 11.0.3.

Comment: Can you try to set fixed width to table?

Comment: it is safari 10.1

Comment: @JanneHarju sorry i cant it gotta be responsive

Comment: @pvg i tested in 11 also and it's not showing (i'm using VM)

Comment: That's odd. Do you see a horizontal scrollbar in your fiddle if you run it in the current Safari Technology Preview?

Comment: no i'm not seeing, i'm using high sierra os provided by browserstack.com

Comment: @JerryGoyal Do you mind if we used jQuery? Please check it out http://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/1zpudt21/3/

Comment: @Liamm12 thanks for the help but no script for this

Comment: Right but there is the Safari Tech Preview which you can install through the appstore on your VM. Trying to get an idea if you're looking at some Safari bug that got fixed or something specific to your setup.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't install anything on those VM's.

Comment: I think I've found the solution, there i applied webkit styles to table but it should be on tbody. here's the working solution http://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/1zpudt21/4/