# React Textarea Input - overflow-y is not showing scrollbar (on Chrome or Edge)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I can't seem to figure out how to show/add scrollbar to a React Textarea. I have referenced this old post here [Preventing scroll bars from being hidden for MacOS trackpad users in WebKit/Blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/preventing-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-macos-trackpad-users-in-webkit-blin) and few others but have not been successful.

I have tested it in both Chrome (Version 113.0.5672.129) and Edge (Version 114.0.1823.37)

Here is what I have:

```
const myComponet = () => {

 return (
    <input type= "textarea" className={styles.largeTextBox} id="someTextBox"/>
   )
}

//Stylesheet
.largeTextBox{
  width: 200px;
  height : 50px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical{
  width:11px;
}

.frame-webkit-scrollbar-track{
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"textarea"` is not a valid type for an `<input>`. You want a `<textarea>` element instead.

```
<textarea className={styles.largeTextBox} id="someTextBox" />
```

Comment: Jeez, had a feeling I was referencing (https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-multiline-text-area-in-reactjs) something wrong. 
Thank you @Unmitigated!