# Resolution independent websites? (Or, "Scaling an entire website to fill the browser")

Tags: jquery, html, css, scaling

I'm working on a project that would really benefit from filling the whole screen -- it's essentially one 7000px-long page with a giant background filling the whole length (probably chopped into separate pieces and loaded in an intelligent sequential fashion in the final version), with 5 or 6 different segments/areas/slides (basically, "content areas") as you scroll down.

At the top is a navigation bar that fills the entire horizontal width of the design. Below it, on the background, are a bunch of different elements, placed at specific positions on the background. The placement on the background is critical as each element is specific to a certain section of the page.

It seems to me doing something like http://windyroad.org/2007/05/18/resolution-independent-web-design/ would be really really useful. Alas, that's from 2007 and seems more like a proof-of-concept than anything. Plus it seems like a bad idea to resize a 1000x7000px image with PHP every time somebody resizes their browser window (Or even worse, five 1000x1000 images!).

I've used jQuery scripts that scale a background image to fill the entire browser, but never ran across anything that scales every element on page.

**Is there any way to dynamically scale an entire website to fit the browser window?**

I'm pretty sure I already know the answer, but figured I'd toss it out there just in case somebody has an idea.

Many thanks!

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: Cool article, hadn't see that before.

Comment: Yep, that article is old and yes it was a proof-of-concept more than anything else. In terms of resizing the image using PHP, there was a never published version 2 of the article that could use a directory of different sized images and serve up the most appropriate or otherwise generate the right size, save it to the directory and serve it up. Anyway that was a very long time ago and the smashingmagazine article looks like it's far more comprehensive, not to mention far more upto date

Answer (score 0):

The script also [calculate the scrollbar size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes/986977#986977) if needed. You will need a block (`div`, `span`, etc...) with the *wrapper* id.

This is a **cross-browser** script, it supports all the modern browsers.

I hope you like it. Feel free to use!

```
// DONT FORGET TO ADD THIS TO YOUR WRAPPER'S CSS BLOCK
// THIS WILL KEEP YOUR SITE CENTERED
// IF YOU USE margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;

// transform-origin: 50% 0%;
// -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
// -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
// -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
// -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;

function FitToScreen(FitType)
{
    var Wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

    var ScreenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var ScreenHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var WrapperWidth = Wrapper.offsetWidth;
    var WrapperHeight = Wrapper.offsetHeight + 200;

    var WidthRatio = parseFloat(ScreenWidth/WrapperWidth);
    var HeightRatio = parseFloat(ScreenHeight/WrapperHeight);

    var ScaleRatio = 1.0;

    if (FitType == 'width')
    {
        ScaleRatio = WidthRatio;
        if(ScaleRatio * WrapperHeight > ScreenHeight)
        {
            ScaleRatio = parseFloat(ScreenWidth/(WrapperWidth + GetScrollBarWidth () -1));
        }
    }
    else if (FitType == 'height')
    {
        ScaleRatio = HeightRatio;
        if(ScaleRatio * WrapperWidth > ScreenWidth)
        {
            ScaleRatio = parseFloat(ScreenHeight/(WrapperHeight + GetScrollBarWidth () -1));
        }
    }

    var ScaleText = 'scale(' + ScaleRatio.toString().replace(',','.') + ')';

    //Chrome and Safari
        Wrapper.style.webkitTransform = ScaleText;
    //Firefox
        Wrapper.style.MozTransform = ScaleText;
    //Internet Explorer
        Wrapper.style.msTransform = ScaleText;
    //Opera
        Wrapper.style.OTransform = ScaleText;
    //Standard
        Wrapper.style.transform = ScaleText;
}

function GetScrollBarWidth ()
{
    var inner = document.createElement('p');
    inner.style.width = '100%';
    inner.style.height = '200px';

    var outer = document.createElement('div');
    outer.style.position = 'absolute';
    outer.style.top = '0px';
    outer.style.left = '0px';
    outer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    outer.style.width = '200px';
    outer.style.height = '150px';
    outer.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    outer.appendChild (inner);

    document.body.appendChild (outer);
    var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
    outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
    if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

    document.body.removeChild (outer);
    return (w1 - w2);
}
```