# Convert pixel to percentage for big monitors

Tags: css, width

I developed a web page with 1000px width. But it is look very small in big monitor(We have 2560x1600 monitor). My questions are

1. How to convert a (or any) website to big screen using percentage instead of pixels ?
2. Any conversion method for pixel to percentage?

I tried width: 100%,.... But it is not for all(padding, margins, line-height,...)

any suggestions?

Thank you...

Comment: I'd suggest you do some research on responsive design. Here's a link to a good place to start: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Yes responsive design is what you should be looking at. Duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620775/resolution-independent-websites-or-scaling-an-entire-website-to-fill-the-bro

Comment: Check this link for convert [pixel to width] may be will help you.

[pixel to width]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358162/converting-width-from-percentage-to-pixels

Comment: you have to calculate its as if your layout is 960px for 1024x768 resolution screen you should (960/1024 * 100) = 93.75 (it means 93.75%) same for all other things. Its good if you use em instead of percentage. Just set your base font size i.e (10/16 * 100)=62.5%. 16 is the default base fontsize of browsers this will make 10px = 1em.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Media Queries?

Check out: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

You can detect the screen size (or intervals of sizes) and apply different CSS to it, regarding element size in your page.