# How to calculate the width of the scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, html, width, scrollbar

Given a `<textarea>` with a fixed `width`, I would like its "active width" to be constant (in `px`). By "active width" I mean the area where the text appears.

When the vertical scroll bar doesn't appear, the "active width" equals to `width`. But, when the vertical scroll bar appears, the "active width" becomes smaller than `width` (I guess smaller exactly by the width of the scroll bar).

I thought to identify whether the vertical scroll bar appears or not, and if yes, to increase the width of the `<textarea>` by the width of the scroll bar. How could I identify the width of the scroll bar?

Is there a better approach?

(I'm interested in Firefox, if it makes the life easier.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the browser's scrollbar sizes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a jQuery plugin that can help with this: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-getscrollbarwidth/blob/master/jquery.getscrollbarwidth.js

Also, from http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=115 
Here is some code that may help.

This creates a hidden `<p>` element at 100% width inside a `<div>` with a scrollbar, then calculates the `<div>` width - the `<p>` width = scroll bar width.

```
function getScrollBarWidth () { 
  var inner = document.createElement('p'); 
  inner.style.width = "100%"; 
  inner.style.height = "200px"; 

  var outer = document.createElement('div'); 
  outer.style.position = "absolute"; 
  outer.style.top = "0px"; 
  outer.style.left = "0px"; 
  outer.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
  outer.style.width = "200px"; 
  outer.style.height = "150px"; 
  outer.style.overflow = "hidden"; 
  outer.appendChild (inner); 

  document.body.appendChild (outer); 
  var w1 = inner.offsetWidth; 
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll'; 
  var w2 = inner.offsetWidth; 
  if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth; 

  document.body.removeChild (outer); 

  return (w1 - w2); 
};
```

Comment: I get the error "cannot ready property 'appendChild' of null"

Answer (score 10):

Scrollbar width is simply (offsetWidth - clientWidth) in a borderless! element.
This function calculates it on the fly and caches the result for further use. No need need for percentage width etc.

```
var getScrollbarWidth = function() {
  var div, width = getScrollbarWidth.width;
  if (width === undefined) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<div style="width:50px;height:50px;position:absolute;left:-50px;top:-50px;overflow:auto;"><div style="width:1px;height:100px;"></div></div>';
    div = div.firstChild;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    width = getScrollbarWidth.width = div.offsetWidth - div.clientWidth;
    document.body.removeChild(div);
  }
  return width;
};
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe this is a more straightforward solution: (assuming `body {width:100%;}`)

```
function calculateScrollBarWidth() {
  return window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth;
}
```

A solution to calculate the scrollbar width of any element (e.g. a div with overflow, or a textarea)

```
function calculateScrollbarWidth(element) {
  if (!element) {
    // Return the body scrollbar width, when no element was specified.
    return window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth;
  } else {
    // When an element is specified, return its specific scrollbar width.
    return element.offsetWidth - element.clientWidth;
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be accpeted answer

Comment: Perfect solution! Here's another sample on how to calculate the scrollbar width of any element (not only the body): https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/get-the-scrollbar-width-of-an-element/

Comment: For me, using Chrome version 89, `window.innerWidth` & `document.documentElement.clientWidth` return the same value

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you could put

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

in your css. This forces the scrollbar to be present even when the text area is blank, so the width is always constant.

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery, simply write:

```
function getScrollBarWidth () {
    var $outer = $('<div>').css({visibility: 'hidden', width: 100, overflow: 'scroll'}).appendTo('body'),
        widthWithScroll = $('<div>').css({width: '100%'}).appendTo($outer).outerWidth();
    $outer.remove();
    return 100 - widthWithScroll;
};
```

Comment: Returns "NaN" - Chrome 54

Comment: Are you sure? It appears to return 0 for me because Chrome's new scrollbars take up no space

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar - here is what i found

```
 function measureScrollbar() {
      var $c = $("<div style='position:absolute; top:-10000px; left:-10000px; width:100px; height:100px; overflow:scroll;'></div>").appendTo("body");
      var dim = {
        width: $c.width() - $c[0].clientWidth,
        height: $c.height() - $c[0].clientHeight
      };
      $c.remove();
      return dim;
    }
```

Source : [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) uses this - https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L378

Or

Use Google Closure Library -[link](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_style_style.js.source.html#line1903)

```
/**
 * Returns the scroll bar width (represents the width of both horizontal
 * and vertical scroll).
 *
 * @param {string=} opt_className An optional class name (or names) to apply
 *     to the invisible div created to measure the scrollbar. This is necessary
 *     if some scrollbars are styled differently than others.
 * @return {number} The scroll bar width in px.
 */
goog.style.getScrollbarWidth = function(opt_className) {
  // Add two hidden divs.  The child div is larger than the parent and
  // forces scrollbars to appear on it.
  // Using overflow:scroll does not work consistently with scrollbars that
  // are styled with ::-webkit-scrollbar.
  var outerDiv = goog.dom.createElement('div');
  if (opt_className) {
    outerDiv.className = opt_className;
  }
  outerDiv.style.cssText = 'overflow:auto;' +
      'position:absolute;top:0;width:100px;height:100px';
  var innerDiv = goog.dom.createElement('div');
  goog.style.setSize(innerDiv, '200px', '200px');
  outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
  goog.dom.appendChild(goog.dom.getDocument().body, outerDiv);
  var width = outerDiv.offsetWidth - outerDiv.clientWidth;
  goog.dom.removeNode(outerDiv);
  return width;
};
```

Comment: the Google Closure Library solution works best, thx! the slickgrid solution is broken see https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/149

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.scrollbar-measure {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}
```

Vanilla JS:

```
// Create the measurement node
var scrollDiv = document.createElement("div");
scrollDiv.className = "scrollbar-measure";
document.body.appendChild(scrollDiv);

// Get the scrollbar width
var scrollbarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth;
console.warn(scrollbarWidth); // Mac:  15

// Delete the DIV 
document.body.removeChild(scrollDiv);
```

[Solution by David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/detect-scrollbar-width)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
var t = jQuery('<textarea/>').css({
    position: 'absolute', 
    top: '-100px',
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    overflowY: 'scroll'
}).prependTo('body'),
w = t[0].offsetWidth - t[0].clientWidth;
console.log('bar width = ', w);
t.remove();
```

*bar width =  18*

Answer (score -1):

I think this helps to get the width of scrollbar.

```
textarea.scrollHeight
```

gives the height so cant this be used..

Comment: Did you test this? When the scroll bar doesn't appear, it still returns a non-zero value.