# Auto hiding vertical scrollbars using css overflow

Tags: css

I came across a problem using css overflow for autohiding the vertical scrollbar. I read in a few articles to use css hover pseudo class to achieve this behaviour and the good thing is I am successful to some extent.

I used both 'scroll' and 'auto' for the overflow-y property. With scroll it works like a charm, but with 'scroll' the problem is even if there is no need to show the scrollbar, it is visible which I feel 'auto' does very well.

But again with 'auto' the problem is there is a 16px(I assume) gap at the right side. Probably it the width of the scrollbar. I wanted the full width. I used a background to explain my problem.

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/9scJE/

```
div.autoscroll {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    margin: 3em;
}

div.autoscroll:hover {
    /* overflow-y: scroll; */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This actually seems like a browser bug to me, but it seems to work like you want if you add `padding-right: 1px` on hover.

```
div.myautoscroll:hover {
     overflow: auto;
     padding-right: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/9scJE/1/

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills. The solution worked for me. I've checked in webkit browsers in mac, FF. I'm yet to check in windows.

Comment: Awesome answer. Also note: adding `border-right: 1px solid gray;` also works. In my case, I did not want to add any padding, but I could live with a thicker border.

Answer (score 2):

You should compensate for the scrollbar with padding.

```
div.autoscroll:hover {
    /* overflow-y: scroll; */
    overflow-y: scroll;
padding-right: 16px;

}
```

However it is better to do this with javascript, since the scrollbar width can slightly differ between browsers. I have used this solution with success: [How to calculate the width of the scroll bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079187/how-to-calculate-the-width-of-the-scroll-bar)

Answer (score 2):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
     opacity:0;
     background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:hover{
     opacity: 1;
}
.container:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
     background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `width: 100%;` when hover on the div:

```
 div.myautoscroll:hover {
     overflow: auto;
     width: 100%;
 }
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9scJE/2/)**</kbd>