# How to write css for fixed header and scrollable table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have table and I need fixed header and scroll able body. I did it but I have a border for it so because of scroll bar header and body is not aligned. I need some help to fix this.

Here is my JSFiddle,

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/Bkg3Z/)

**CSS**

```
    table.tableSection {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
table.tableSection thead, table.tableSection tbody {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
table.tableSection tbody {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 150px;
}
table.tableSection tr {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    text-align: left;
}
table.tableSection th, table.tableSection td {
    width: 33%;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: So what is your attempt? I do not understand what your problem is.

Comment: @F.Müller, he hasn't made an attempt to solve the problem in his code, he has said he made it scrollable, the problem arose and now he is here for an answer.

Comment: @F.Müller my problem is if scrollbar appears header and body borders are not aligned properly, how can i solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to use jquery to identify whether your table body content have scrollbar or not. Next you need to toggle one class with the calculation of adding scrollbar width. So here is the solution with that.

**HTML**

```
 <table class="tableSection">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><span class="text">album</span>

        </th>
        <th><span class="text">song</span>

        </th>
        <th><span class="text">genre</span>

        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="mytest">
    <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>        </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>        </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
 table.tableSection {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
table.tableSection thead, table.tableSection tbody {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
table.tableSection tbody {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 150px;    
}
table.tableSection tr {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    text-align: left;
}
table.tableSection th, table.tableSection td {
    width: 33%;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.extrawidth{
    width:calc(100% - 18px) !important;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
(function($) {
$.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
    return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
}
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){    
 if($('#mytest').hasScrollBar())
 {
   $('.tableSection thead').toggleClass('extrawidth');
 }
});
```

[**Have a Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/Bkg3Z/4/)

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai this worked fine but I have another table, in that i have 7 columns and i cant fix the width of each `<td>` so how can i fix that.

Comment: Here you have assigned to 33% for 3 columns. like 7 columns use 14%.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I did that but didnt work , can you see my fiddel, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/56Ce8/

Comment: Add "word-break:break-all;" property for your table cell. check this updated fiddel of yours. http://jsfiddle.net/56Ce8/2/

Comment: we have fixed width for table column. if you are adding any length text without space like "sdfsfdsfsfsdfsfsdfsfdsfdsfsdfsf", table will allow to show the entire text if it is more than the assigned width also. This CSS property will stop this behavior. Check it in google to get more idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
table.tableSection thead {
    float: left;
    width: 97%;
}
```

Add this to your css

Comment: Surely that solution only works if the table is dragged to a specific width? Else it will just fall out of sync again.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the table a fixed size, you can split it into two.
The headers which are lets say 500px, and the content which is 500px + the width of the scrollbar.

Either you can approximate it (around 12px) as can be seen on the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkg3Z/3/):

```
table.tableSection {
    display: table;
    width: 500px;
}
table.tableSection thead, table.tableSection tbody {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
table.tableSection tbody {
    overflow: auto;
    width:512px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

or use Javascript to work out the size of the scrollbar and add it to the tables width using the solution proposed on [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079187/how-to-calculate-the-width-of-the-scroll-bar)

Comment: this is fine but cant we fix table for 100% because i am designing responsive web page. So I dont have to use px more.

Comment: You could add it to the padding of the header table instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Bkg3Z/5/

Comment: can you pls help me to fix this jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/56Ce8

Comment: This question already has a different accepted answer. If you have a different problem best post it as a different question.

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
  width: 916px; /* every td or th in thead + 16px for scrollbar */
}

tbody, thead tr{
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  text-align:center;
}

tbody td, thead th {
   width: 225px;
}

thead th:last-child {
  width: 241px; /* td + 16px for scrollbar */
}
```

Of course you can give the width you want.

This is what I used for my page and it works great.