# (total html novice) How to keep webpage from having a scroll bar and instead resize the site to fit within the browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scale

My main issue is that when you click a button on my site ([www.typo.video](https://www.typo.video)) it takes you to a different page of the site but it jumps back to the top when I'd like for the view not to change relative to the background. The obvious solution to me is to not allow the page to overflow and instead have the whole site scale to the size of the window (similar to using ctr +/- in the browser to zoom), but I cannot figure out how.

I've tried a few solutions, but it's possible I didn't implement them correctly because I am not coding the site from scratch. I am using a website builder through NameCheap and I don't always know what folders/files I should be editing the code in to affect certain aspects of the site. I am a fast learner and have some limited coding experience but I only started messing with html/css in the past few days.

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595446/any-way-to-auto-zoom-browser-based-upon-users-browser-window) solution could work from the sounds of it, but if I'm not mistaken I would need to essentially put the whole site into a container and I am not sure where amongst the files I would implement that.

If anyone has a solution it would be helpful to know what I am looking for in terms of where to put the code/what phrases I should be looking for. (See image of [relevant folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXalf.png)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit this id, replace the values with the commented ones.

```
#wb_main_11 {
  width: 1920px; /* 100% or 100vh */
  height: 1080px; /* 100vh */
  /* once you change the above, you probably don't need the ones bellow */
  min-width: 1920px; /* 100vh or 100% */
  min-height: 1080px; /* 100vh or 100% */
  max-width: 1920px;
  max-height: 1080px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
```

}

Also the image your have a "max-width: 100%" rules, after doing that, the button are the last element making your page to overflow, so reposition them