# jQuery window width not equal to CSS's window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following two pieces of CSS and JS code:

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
    // a code to make arrows in a carousel disappear
}

if(jQuery(window).width() <= 720){
    // a code to make arrows in the carousel stop working
}
```

The problem with them is that the latter executes on exactly width=738px and not 720px. I suspect that this is because of browser's vertical scrollbar that has width equal to 18px in Chrome.

Is there a way to unify this? I'd like these actions to happen at the same moment in all browsers regardless of the scrollbar's width.

Tests (when browser is @ 720px and CSS has already executed):

```
jQuery(document).innerWidth() = 703
jQuery(window).innerWidth() = 703
jQuery(document).width() = 703
jQuery(window).width() = 703
jQuery('body').width() = 703
jQuery('html').width() = 703
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to tackle the same problem a while ago, and so far the most correct solution I found is to use media queries to pass the actual window size to Javascript. You have to follow these steps:

- Add a hidden element to your page,
- Use media queries to alter the `max-width` property of that element,
- Read back the `max-width` property of that element through Javascript.

For instance, add the following element to your page:

```html
<div id="currentMedia"></div>
```

Then write the following CSS rules:

```css
#currentMedia {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
    /* Make arrows in the carousel disappear... */

    #currentMedia {
        max-width: 720px;
    }
}
```

Then, from the Javascript side, you can write:

```js
if (parseInt(jQuery("#currentMedia").css("max-width"), 10) <= 720) {
    // Make arrows in the carousel stop working...
}
```

And it will be accurate regardless of the scrollbar size, since the value comes from the same media query that triggers the carousel's disappearance.

I tested this solution on all major recent browsers, and it gives correct results.

Comment: That's smart, thanks! So, there is no plain jQuery way to do this?

Comment: @Atadj, not to my knowledge, no.

Answer (score 6):

You will find the big summary of what properties are supported on what browsers [on this page on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html).

Your best bet is probably to grab an element in the page (using document.body where supported, or document.getElementById or whatever), walk its offsetParent chain to find the topmost element, then examine that element's clientWidth and clientHeight.

[innerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) documentation

`innerWidth()` says this method is not applicable to `window` and `document` objects; for these, use .width()

try

[How can I get the browser's scrollbar sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes)

From [Alexandre Gomes Blog](http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=115)

```
function getScrollBarWidth () {
  var inner = document.createElement('p');
  inner.style.width = "100%";
  inner.style.height = "200px";

  var outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.style.position = "absolute";
  outer.style.top = "0px";
  outer.style.left = "0px";
  outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  outer.style.width = "200px";
  outer.style.height = "150px";
  outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
  outer.appendChild (inner);

  document.body.appendChild (outer);
  var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
  var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
  if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

  document.body.removeChild (outer);

  return (w1 - w2);
};
```

in your code

```
if(jQuery(window).width()-getScrollBarWidth(); <= 720){
    // a code to make arrows in the carousel stop working
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) for `innerWidth()` says *this method is not applicable to `window` and `document` objects; for these, use `.width()` instead*.

Comment: I tried this but I think that it doesn't work. I used `console.log()` to print the value and these are the results: http://gyazo.com/ccba301317849b000666efe3e5bdc201.png (when viewport is 734px it thinks it's 717px. JavaScript executes earlier than CSS media query.

Comment: Those 17px difference sounds like the width of a browser scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

A bit outdated thread, but i've found this solution

```
function getWidth(){
   return ((window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap > 3 then I will suggest you something.

Bootstrap ships with `.container` class in its Css and predefined. And its altering with @media queries.So my working code sample for this is below.

```
function detectWidth(){
   var width = $('.container').eq(0).outerWidth()   ;
   console.log(width);
   if(width<750){
     // do something for XS element
   }else if(width>=750 && width<970){
     // do something for SM element
   }else if(width>=970 && width<1170){
      // do something for MD element
   }else{
    // do something for LG element
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but I think it can still benefit from this answer.

```
var width = window.outerWidth;
```

This will give you the width of the window including scrollbars, which is what media queries use, I believe.