# iPad, iPhone modal dialog scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

Various pages on our website open up JQuery 'Modal Dialog' boxes.

These work fine in every web browser.

However a problem occurs when viewing on an iPad or iPhone, and i believe this is a common issue.

On some pages the modal dialog box is too big for the iPad screen, therefore i need to scroll the modal box.

However when I do this dialog box doesnt move, but the background (i.e. the main screen behind it) scrolls.

I want to disable the background from scrolling when the modal is open but enable the modal dialog to scroll.

I have tried 'position:fixed' underneath the 'overflow:hidden' which has solved the issue for others, unfortunately for me, the issue still exists.

Does anyone have any other ideas/things that I can try?

Below is an example of the code for one of the pages that opens in a modal dialog box.

Thanks

```
<script>
    function myOnLoad() {
        window.parent.$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

    }   

</script>



<body onload="myOnLoad()">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="popup" class="modalDialog2"> 

 <!--DIALOG CONTENT HERE-->


</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    // close Modal
    $("#close").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.parent.$('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    window.parent.$("iframe").attr('src');
    window.parent.$(".modalDialog").removeClass('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Add working code snippet on http://codepen.io please.

Comment: No worries, i have found an answer to my problem.

Comment: Then you should post answer to your own question or delete it.

Comment: This snippet of code and corresponding link did the trick...

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/problem-with-dialog-scroll-on-ipad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent background scrolling when Bootstrap 3 modal open on mobile browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060301/how-to-prevent-background-scrolling-when-bootstrap-3-modal-open-on-mobile-browse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION

This snippet of code and corresponding [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/problem-with-dialog-scroll-on-ipad) did the trick...

```
$(function(){
    if (/iPhone|iPod|iPad/.test(navigator.userAgent))
        $('iframe').wrap(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            return $('<div />').css({
                width: $this.attr('width'),
                height: $this.attr('height'),
                overflow: 'scroll',
                '-webkit-overflow-scrolling': 'touch'
            });
        });
})
```

Answer (score 16):

I had the issue, lines of code below resolved it for me -

```
html{ 
    overflow: scroll; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: For me it worked without: overflow:scroll; but just with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;