# Unable to get scrollbar width in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the scrollbar width in Mozilla Firefox like this:

```
var scrollWt = div.offsetWidth - div.clientWidth - borderLeft - borderRight;
var scrollHt = div.offsetHeight - div.clientHeight - borderTop - borderBottom;
```

This is working fine in Webkit browsers, but in firefox both the values are `0`. After debugging I found that in Firefox, `clientHeight` and `clientWidth` are same as `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`, just excluding `border` values.

How do I fix the above code to get the correct scrollbar size?

Edit:

I have tried `scrollWidth` too. No luck!

Comment: how to "fix" this "issue"? you mean the default browser behavior?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Sarcastic! updated the question :)

Comment: Hmm well even MDN says that "clientWidth" is supposed to exclude the width of the scroll bar.

Comment: @Pointy Any hack or Firefox specific methods to fix this?

Comment: something along these lines might be a good starting point => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes