# jquery dialog overlays scrollbar when the window has a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jquery dialog to show a dialog. I am able to place it bottom left corner which is where I want it. Trouble is if the main window has a scrollbar, the dialog goes to `bottom left` of the scrollbar, thereby overlaying the scrollbar. One would expect that `bottom left` of the window means `bottom right` of the scrollbar and not the `bottom left` of the scrollbar.

I have tried specifying [position object](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) option to jquery dialog without success. I have tried all four values `fit, flip, flipfit and none` of the collision option in the position object. But none of them seem to do the trick.

I know there is a hacky way to calculate the width of the scrollbar and move the dialog by that much and I have already employed this hack in a number of places. But I am hoping for an API way of doing it.

Does anybody know of a way ?

**Actual Behaviour**

[image]

**Expected Behaviour**

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some HTML? I have a theory on that one.

Comment: JSFIDDLE will be greate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real way to do this, all browsers suck at displaying scrollbars on the left. The ideal way is not to use the scrollbars on the left. Most famous news paper websites in Hebrew and Arabic seem to use right scrollbars. So, the defacto standard is to use a scrollbar on the right irrespective of the language.

This is not the only problem that a left scrollbar introduces.

- Safari won't even show a scrollbar on the left even if you mark the html `RTL`.
- Firefox shows the scrollbar on the left. But it mangles the absolute left and top calculation.

  - Let's suppose you have an image inside html marked `RTL`. You want to overlay a div over the image. So you need to get the left, top, width and height of the image. Your scrollbar is on the left because it is a `RTL` language. When you ask for the dimensions of the image, firefox will return correct dimensions. Now if you apply these dimensions to a div that you want to overlay on the image, firefox will consider the right-top side of the left scrollbar as the origin. Notice that the image was rendered with left-top of the left scrollbar as the origin, therefore your overlay is off by scrollbar width.
- Chrome seems to be the only browser that implements this well. But because other browsers don't implement this well, we end up doing browser specific stuff anyway.
- IE9 and IE8 behave exactly like Firefox.

Anyway, my answer is more of a rant so other people might find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The following example worked for me ([**code**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/6CUrp/), [**fullscreen**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/6CUrp/show/)):

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    position: {
        my: "right bottom",
        at: "right bottom",
        of: window
    }
});
```

Note that the code is wrapped in [**`$(function(){})`**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) construct which means that the dialog is created after DOM is loaded and the browser has calculated whether a scrollbar is needed or not. Perhaps you are calling the dialog too early.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are on a Mac with those pesky auto hiding scrollbars? What you could try is use CSS to always show the scrollbar on the body:

```
body { overflow-y: scroll }
```

Comment: Nope, I am on windows. Scrollbars are always showing on page load. But then I click a button to open the dialog. The dialog shows over the scrollbar hiding the scrollbar.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Beats me, I'm sorry. Might be a browser bug because of right-to-left reading? Have you tried the reverse? If the scrollbar is really the actual 'hard coded' scrollbar of your browser window, and not of any HTML element inside the body, I would say that it's impossible to put any HTML element over that scrollbar. I'd probably hack my way out of it as well, in this case

Comment: Oh! it is the same behaviour even for LTR. And all browsers are doing the same thing. Yep, that is not a custom scrollbar, the body element has a `overflow: auto;` which is creating that scrollbar. This is not the only location where I noticed this problem. For what ever reason browsers are not including scrollbars in left and top calculations. I suppose when they suck they all suck equally well. Anyway, thanks for trying.

Comment: Think about the consequences if they wouldn't... positioning something atop a overflow:

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to define the area inside the div minus the scrollbar because the scrollbar is within the div. The scrollbar doesn't exist as a container.  At least this is the case when you use css and set `overflow: scroll`.  It may be possible with some of the jQuery plugins for Scrollbars.

The best I can do is offset the position by a standard `20px` wide space.  Here is what I used.

```
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        position: { 
            my: 'right bottom',
            at: 'right-20px bottom',
            of: $("#some_div")
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is no real way to do this, all browsers suck at displaying scrollbars on the left. You get the points as your answer is the closest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this at css

```
#dialog{
   position: fixed;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this trick may help you on getting the scrollbar width for any browser, you can use it as a function:

[How can I get the browser's scrollbar sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes)

and if you're woried about leaving the white space if the scrollbar isn't showing, you can force it with css:

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```