# javascript: failed to get scroll bar height accurately

Tags: javascript, html, document

I was trying to get the scroll bar height, after some time i found a idea to get the height:

CSS:

```
#content {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#bt {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 10px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="barHeight()">Press it</button>

 <div id="bt"></div>

 <div id="content">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex.................
 </div>
```

JS:

```
function barHeight() {
 var scrHeight = window.innerHeight; // supposed to be 799 px
 var contentBox = document.getElementById("content");
 var contentHeight = contentBox.scrollHeight; //
 var targetHeight = ( ( scrHeight / contentHeight ) * 100 );
 var testBox = document.getElementById("bt");

 if(scrHeight < contentHeight) {
    testBox.style.height = targetHeight + "%";
 } else if( scrHeight > contentHeight ) {
    testBox.innerHTML = "0px";
 }


}
```

but when i measured it then its not accurate height as the actual scroll bar looks like.

Thanks in advance!

edited:
[How can I get the browser's scrollbar sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes) the solution in that link doesn't work for me, at least my script can easily be run and it works for me but not accurately,

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another way.

The `isScrollable (...)` function check if the `content` div is overflowed and can be scrolled (an element with `overflow: hidden` is still scrollable though its scrollbar is hidden).

The `getScrollBarSize (...)` gets the width of a vertical scrollbar (a horizontal scrollbar has the same height).

```js
function barHeight() {    
 if(isScrollable(document.getElementById("content"))) {
    document.getElementById("bt").innerHTML = getScrollBarSize() + "px";
 } else {
    document.getElementById("bt").innerHTML = "0px";
 }
}

function getScrollBarSize () {
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.setAttribute("style", "width:80px;height:80px;overflow:scroll;position: absolute;visibility:hidden;");
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  var elw = el.offsetWidth - el.clientWidth;
  document.body.removeChild(el);
  return (elw);
  
}
function isScrollable (el) {
  return el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight;  
};
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 300px;
}
#content {
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#bt {
    background-color: #9f9;
    width: 100px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="barHeight()">Press it</button>

 <div id="bt"></div>

 <div id="content">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex.................<br>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex.................<br>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex.................<br>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex.................<br>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex.................<br>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex.................<br>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex.................<br>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex.................<br>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex.................<br>
 </div>
```

Comment: @forweb So i did. Can't see how this is not working? .. When space is available it sizes the `bt` div, when not, not.

Comment: @forweb Are we talking about the size of the scrollbar itself, which is normally 16-22px wide (or high, if it's the horizontal scrollbar) ?