# When option in select list doesn't fix into select width it's value is trimmed if we select it

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a select list with multiple options.

List itself is limited by width. Most of options are expected to fit into lists width, but there could be once that are longer, and I should handle this situation.

`overflow-x:scroll` helps me to see the the long option values (by scrolling via x axis), but I have onether problem: when I select a long option (that doen't fit into select width) and scroll x-asis, text inside my option is trimmed to select lenth. But I want it to be fully displayed when scrolling.

Note: I know a solution with appying auto-width on select, but I'm not allowed to change the width here. It should stay the same.

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

```html
 <select multiple size="5">
       <option>Option1</option>
       <option>Option2</option>
       <option>Option3</option>
       <option>Some Very Long Option</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Why not using select option default instead of showing all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this:

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
select option:checked{
  background:#1E90FF;
  color:#fff;
  display: inline-block;
  /*display:inline-block; (or) display: table;width: 100%;*/
}
```

```html
<select multiple size="5">
       <option>Option1</option>
       <option>Option2</option>
       <option>Option3</option>
       <option>Some Very Long Option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @IvanNikolaychuk Welcome :-)

Comment: This solution has a bug.
Try to click on first item and drag down.
All items are put in first line.

Comment: @SFin Try this select option:checked {background: #1E90FF;color: #fff;display: table;width: 100%;}

Answer (score 1):

try to calculate width dynamically, for e.g.

```js
//taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes
function getScrollBarWidth () {
  var inner = document.createElement('p');
  inner.style.width = "100%";
  inner.style.height = "200px";

  var outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.style.position = "absolute";
  outer.style.top = "0px";
  outer.style.left = "0px";
  outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  outer.style.width = "200px";
  outer.style.height = "150px";
  outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
  outer.appendChild (inner);

  document.body.appendChild (outer);
  var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
  var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
  if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

  document.body.removeChild (outer);

  return (w1 - w2);
};

var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
select.style.width =select.scrollWidth+ getScrollBarWidth();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple size="5">
       <option>Option1</option>
       <option>Option2</option>
       <option>Option3</option>
  <option>Option1</option>
       <option>Option2</option>
       <option>Option3</option>
  <option>Option1</option>
       <option>Option2</option>
       <option>Option3</option>
       <option>Some Very Long Option</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: It changes initial width, unfortunately.
And actually looks to complicated for me.
Thanks, anyway!

Comment: I have a dual selectlist and I was trying to add scroll-x and did not have any luck.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest `overflow-x:visible` and display property for `selected box` will work

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x:visible;
}
select option:checked{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<select multiple size="5">
       <option>Option1</option>
       <option>Option2</option>
       <option>Option3</option>
       <option>Some Very Long Option</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: @IvanNikolaychuk value is not trimming this time

Comment: when I select "Some Very Long Option" and scroll x-asix it's trimmed to "Some Very Lo"

Comment: oh i see this now i will shortly back