# How can I determine the width of the big scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked lots of times (the main proposed solution is: `window.innerWidth` - `document.documentElement.clientWidth`). On Chrome version 89, for me, both these values return the same value. All other answers I've tried (including this one: [How can I get the browser's scrollbar sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes)) don't work.

Btw, I'm trying to determine the width of the 'general' page scrollbar. It would be nice to have this because it does affect the layout.

Are there any cross-browser solutions to this?

---

Example of scroll-bar:

[image: example]

Comment: I suspect those values are equal because there is no scrollbar where you tested.

Comment: Do you know what I mean when I say the general scrollbar? I've attached a screenshot to show you an example

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySWrJ.png

Comment: @Theraot As my question states, both those values return the same value for me (e.g. `window.innerWidth` - `document.documentElement.clientWidth` is `0`(px)

Comment: @Theraot in your screenshot was that a Chrome browser? The scrollbar looks really old fashioned.

Comment: Yes, that is Google Chrome, and it is up to date. That screenshot has a custom theme (by Yulia Brodskaya, you can search it), I tried without it, and got the same result. It is Windows 10, don't know if that makes any difference.