# How to call ajax while scrolling inner scroll of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to call ajax function while scrolling inner scroll and append the results at the bottom of the existing results.

For refrence I've attached an image here.

[image]

How can I achive this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986763/jquery-how-to-determine-that-a-div-is-scrolled-down

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this without jQuery also

```
  window.onload = function(){
     if(window.addEventListener){
        document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', moveObject, false);
     }

    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        myDiv.onmousewheel = ajaxFunction();
    }
```